# Intellij Idea OS X permission denied

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Good evening.
I'm imported project in Intellij Idea and when I'm trying to build and run it I have an error with saving

```
Could not save project:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException:/Development/myDatabase/DBcourse/SimpleDatabase/.idea/workspace.xml___jb_bak___ (Permission  denied)
```

And I have the same problem to class access.

I don't want to change Only Read file access to Read+Write for all files in project folder.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives: change the user of this particular .idea folder.
or change the access rights of the .idea folder +x+w.